# ASM debugging : How to watch registers in GUD's speedbar?

Tags: gdb, gud, speedbar

I'm trying to debug a programm written in ASM with GDB through Emacs's GUD interface.

I've enabled (`gdb-many-windows`), set a watchpoint on `$rax` which gives me the changes of the register's value in GDB's shell during debugging.
But when I `M-x speedbar-get-focus` from the GDB/GUD's panel, it only displays `Watch Expressions:` and nothing else.

Did I miss something or is displaying registers contents simply not possible in speedbar?